# Triangulable manifolds vs manifolds admitting a handle decomposition

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, triangulation

In differential topology we have a chain of strict inclusions
$$\mathsf{Diff} \subsetneq \mathsf{PL} \subsetneq \mathsf{Triang} \subsetneq \mathsf{Top}$$
among the classes of smooth, PL, triangulable and topological manifolds, respectively.

Now consider the class $\mathsf{Handle}$ of topological manifolds that admit a handle decomposition.

> **Question:** Does $\mathsf{Handle}$ fit in the previous sequence? (and if it does, where?)

Any PL manifold admits a handle decomposition and for that (e.g. see Rourke,  Sanderson, *Introduction to piecewise-linear topology*) one can argue with a triangulation coming from the PL structure. Of course, this will be a combinatorial triangulation, but there are triangulable manifolds that do not admit any PL structure.

It feels to me that $\mathsf{Handle}$ and $\mathsf{Triang}$ are not contained one in the other, but I don't know any counterexamples.

Comment: I don’t know what a handle decomposition is, but anything described as a scalar field can be triangulated using, say, Marching Cubes.

Comment: Triang $\subset$ Handle in general, while Handle=Top except in dimension 4, where Handle=PL=Triang.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Do you have any reference for these facts?

Comment: @MoisheKohan and more particularly, do you have an example of a manifold admitting a handle decomposition but not a triangulation?

Comment: The first one is obvious, the second is Kirby-Siebenmann's book. For your other comment, if you want an example, then it's not me, of course, but is the negative solution of the Triangulation Conjecture by Manolescu, https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.08163.